# Asymptotic time complexity of List.fold and foldBack

Tags: algorithm, f#, complexity-theory, f#-interactive

I am trying to understand the time complexity for these two functions. I have tried experimenting with both and here is what I have come up with

```
List.foldBack (@) [[1];[2];[3];[4]] [] => [1] @ List.foldBack (@) [[2];[3];[4]] []
=> [1] @ ([2] @ List.foldBack (@) [[3];[4]] [])
=> [1] @ ([2] @ ([3] @ List.foldBack (@) [4] []))
=> [1] @ ([2]@([3] @ ([4] @ List.foldBack[])))
=> [1]@([2]@([3]@([4]@([])))
=> [1; 2; 3; 4]


List.fold (@) [] [[1];[2];[3];[4]]
=> List.fold (@) (([],[1])@ [2]) [[3];[4]]
=> List.fold (@)  ((([]@[1])@[2])@[3]) [[4]]
=> List.fold (@)  (((([]@[1])@[2])@[3])@[4]) []
=> (((([]@[1])@[2])@[3])@[4])
```

Now it seems to me that they are both linear since it takes the same amount of calculations to achieve the same result. Am i correct or is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If each inner operation is Θ(1), `List.fold` and `List.foldBack` is O(n) where `n` is the length of the list.

However, to estimate asymptotic time complexity, you need to rely on Θ(1) operations. In your example, things are a little more subtle.

Suppose you need to concatenate `n` lists where each list has `m` elements. Since `@` is `O(n)` of the length of the left operand, we have complexity of `foldBack`:

```
  m + ... + m // n occurences of m
= O(m*n)
```

and that of `fold`:

```
  0 + m + 2*m + ... + (n-1)*m // each time length of left operand increases by m
= m*n*(n-1)/2
= O(m*n^2)
```

Therefore, with your naive way of using `@`, `foldBack` is linear while `fold`is quadratic to the size of input lists.

It is worth to note that `@` is associative (a @ (b @ c) = (a @ b) @ c); therefore, results are the same for `fold` and `foldBack` in this case.

In practice, if the inner operator is non-associative, we need to choose the right order by either using `fold` or `foldBack`. And `List.foldBack` in F# is made tail-recursive by transforming lists to arrays; there are some overheads by this operation as well.

Answer (score 3):

The `List.fold` and `List.foldBack` functions are both T(*n*) calls to their function argument where *n* is the length of the list. However, you are passing them the `(@)` function which is not T(1) but T(*m*) where *m* is the length of the first argument list.

In particular, this:

```
(((([]@[1])@[2])@[3])@[4])
```

is T(*n*²) because `[1]@[2]` is one operation and then `[1;2]@[3]` is two more operations and then `[1;2;3]@[4]` is three more operations.

Answer (score 2):

In a naive implementation `FoldBack` is `O(n^2)` as you need to keep traversing the list.  In F# the compiler actually creates a temporary array and reverses it and then calls `Fold`, so the time complexity (in terms of `O`) is `O(n)` for both, although `Fold` will be slightly faster by a constant amount